# Regular expression: Getting only the 2 letters before punctuation

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

Anyone can help me to formulate the best regular expression line for getting the State on this phrase:

`Work Location Tucson AZ (5255 E. Williams Cir - 13002)`

Result will be getting **AZ** only

I have this regular expression but the thing is it also getting the punctuation as a result.

Regular expression: `[A-Z]{2} \(`

Result: **AZ (**

Comment: You can either use capturing groups to just capture the letters. Or you can use look aheads.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I managed to solved this by using a c# code trim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

positive lookahead works just fine. Try this

```
[A-Z]{2}\s(?=\()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to give you the best answer without knowing more about your data set, but (?:\w+\s){3}(\w{2})\s will always grab fourth word if it's two characters long.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, but I guess it wouldn't be always comes in fourth word. There are locations like: Work Location **Los Angeles** CA so in this case it might not be applicable.

Comment: So will it always be the last word?  The word immediately to the left of a open parentheses?  What extraction logic would you like the expression to use?